# Show that the profile of the hill is a cycloid

Tags: physics, applications

I'm struggling with this problem:

From George Simmons_ Differential Equations

> At sunset a man is standing at the base of a dome-shaped hill where if
>   faces the setting sun. He throws a rock straight up in such a manner
>   that the highest point it reaches is level with the top of the hill.
>   As the rock rises, its shadow moves up the surface of the hill at a
>   constant speed. Show that the profile of the hill is a cycloid.

I've tried different things and I showed that the $x$ component and the $y$ component of the shadow should move with constant speed, but nothing really other than that.

Comment: Cross-posted on Phys.SE: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133378/show-that-the-profile-of-the-hill-is-a-cycloid

Comment: I didn't really know where to post it. Because it's a physics question on a Differential Equations Book

Answer (score 1):

Let $u$ be the constant speed of the shadow on the hill. Choose the origin of time to be such that the vertical velocity (virtual before the time of projection) of the projected particle is $u-gt$ at time $t$ (and so equal to $u$ at $t=0$). At time $t$, let $\psi$ be the angle between the horizontal and the tangent to the hill at the shadow point, and let $s$ be the distance along the profile of the hill to the point from some origin. Then$$\frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dt}=u\quad\text{and}\quad u\sin\psi=u-gt.$$By integration,$$s=\frac{u^2}g(1-\sin\psi),$$where we have chosen the origin of $s$ to be such that $s=0$ when $\psi=\frac12\pi$ and $t=0$. The above equation is the $s$–$\psi$ equation of a cycloid*, whose (local) summit is given by $(s,\psi)=(u^2/g,0)$, corresponding to $t=u/g$. Let us measure any height $y$ vertically from where $s=0$ on the cycloid. Then the hill is of height $u^2/g$. The projectile just attains this height if its general height equation is$$y=\frac{u^2}{2g}+ut-\frac{gt^2}2,$$where the constant term is determined by the given condition $y=u^2/g$ when the vertical velocity is zero, namely when $t=u/g$.

*The parametric cartesian equivalent form of the cycloid equation is$$x=a(\theta-\sin\theta),\qquad y=a(1-\cos\theta),$$where $a=\frac12u^2/g,\,$ $\theta=\pi-2\psi$, and the origin for $x$ and $y$ is the same as the origin for $s$.

Comment: Why is it justified to assume that the speed of the shadow is equal to the speed of the rock at t=0? Isn't this equivalent to assuming that the foot of the hill is vertical?

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by $s-\psi$ equation of a cycloid? Can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: @Cheng : The chosen origin of time puts the virtual foot of the hill at a cusp of the cycloid. In general. this point is underground, and the visible hill is only the upper part of the cycloid. The visible foot of the hill, level with the point of projection, is generally not vertical, and the projection speed ($=u-gt$) is generally less than $u$. $\qquad\qquad$ The intrinsic coordinates $s$ and $\psi$ are defined in the third sentence of the answer. An intrinsic ($s,\psi$) equation of the cycloid is given [here](http://astrowww.phys.uvic.ca/~tatum/classmechs/class19.pdf).